# WHERE IN psycopg2 clause not formatting

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have been having trouble using `WHERE $VARIABLE IN` clauses in psycopg2:

```py
from app.commons.database import conn

from psycopg2 import sql
from psycopg2.extras import DictCursor

query = '''
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        {}.{}
    WHERE
        {} in %s
    '''.format(
        sql.Identifier('information_schema'),
        sql.Identifier('tables'),
        sql.Identifier('table_schema')
    )

data = (
    'information_schema',
    'pg_catalog'
)

with conn.cursor(cursor_factory=DictCursor) as cursor:
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    print(cursor.fetchall())
```

raises

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I've read the seemingly hundreds of posts on this same topic, and the overwhelming answer has been: "you need to use tuples when submitting data as the second argument to `cursor.execute`". I've been doing that and still can't seem to determine where the gap is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the psycopg2 documentation on [Lists adaptation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#lists-adaptation)

You are getting that error because psycopg2 is trying to substitute the two parameters, but you only gave it one parameter.  Try changing to this:

```
from app.commons.database import conn

from psycopg2 import sql
from psycopg2.extras import DictCursor

query = '''
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        {}.{}
    WHERE
        {} =ANY(%s)
    '''.format(
        sql.Identifier('information_schema'),
        sql.Identifier('tables'),
        sql.Identifier('table_schema')
    )

data = [
    'information_schema',
    'pg_catalog'
] # A list now, instead of a tuple

with conn.cursor(cursor_factory=DictCursor) as cursor:
    cursor.execute(query, (data, )) # A tuple, containing your list
    print(cursor.fetchall())
```